# What makes bootstrap badge not showing in condition?

Tags: html, twig, bootstrap-5

In my base template: base.html.twig, i have

```
{% if app.user.getReceivedMessage | length > 0 %}
    {% set urm = 0 %}
    {% for msg in app.user.getReceivedMessage %}
        {% if not msg.getIsRead %}
            {% set urm = urm + 1 %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% if urm is defined %}
    <span class="position-absolute top-75 end-15 translate-middle p-1-5 bg-danger rounded-circle">
        <span class="visually-hidden">New alerts</span> // The badge appears here.
    </span>
{% endif %}
```

Now in the index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
// code lines
{% if urm is defined %}
    Inbox    
    <span class="badge bg-danger ms-3">{{ 0 }}</span> // Not printed, seems urm is not set
{% endif %}
// Somewhere down
{% include 'inbox.html.twig' %}
```

But in the inbox.html.twig i have

```
        {% if urm is defined %} // all this is printed so urm is defined here
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <h3 class="font-light mb-0">
                    <i class="fas fa-email mr-2"></i>
                    {{ urm }}
                    New messages</h3>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
```

The urm is defined in the base template, not defined in the index but defined in the inbox(who is inside the index). Really confused

How can i solve this issue please?

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://twigfiddle.com/u99u1f). Please verify if the `span` is not appearing in the generated HTML and that the word `Inbox` is indeed displayed due to the snippet. Maybe the `span` gets hidden by CSS

Comment: In my case it doesn't even appear in the html when is display the source code in the browser.

Comment: Well are you sure `urm` is defined then?

Comment: I've done this now `{% if not urm is defined %} Inbox<span class="badge bg-danger ms-3">{{ 0 }}</span>{% endif %}` and it appears now. Wow, but urm is defined, i set it at the beginning and i use it in some div after this one. Why can it be not defined here since in the following codes it is defined?

Comment: Could you add a bit more of the template you are using? Especially the part where you defined `urm`? Do note if you set `urm` in an included template, then this variable is only known inside that said template and not outside of it;

Comment: It is okay, i fixed it. I was rendering two files with the name index,html.twig but i was working in the wrong one. it was not the one displayed. It's okay thanks for your time